# Shouldn't the [auth:sanctum] middleware reject requests that have only web authentication?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-sanctum

I have a test that is failing unexpectedly, and I'm wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing. Basically, I want to test an API endpoint returns the appropriate responses depending on common case scenarios (unauthenticated user, forbidden actions, invalid data, valid data, etc).

I am using sanctum and (to me), it does not make sense for this api endpoint to work with other forms of authentication. However, this test is failing.

`PostControllerTest`

```php
public function test_should_return_401()
{
    $user = User::factory()->create();
    
    $response = $this->actingAs($user, 'web')->postJson(route('posts.store'), []);

    $response->assertStatus(401);
}
```

---

I have checked the route is using the `auth:sanctum` middleware.

`routes/api.php`

```php
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('posts');
});
```

And there does not seem to be anything out of the ordinary in the default middleware...

`Middleware/Kernel`

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        'throttle:api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

...or the service provider.

`RouteServiceProvider`

```php
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('api')
            ->prefix('api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    });
}
```

---

Am I missing something or is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

It would not fail since you can use the same middleware `auth:sanctum` for both web and api call, and as it is [written in the Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#protecting-routes)

> This guard will ensure that incoming requests are authenticated as either stateful, cookie authenticated requests or contain a valid API token header if the request is from a third party.

> You may be wondering why we suggest that you authenticate the routes within your application's routes/web.php file using the sanctum guard. Remember, Sanctum will **first** attempt to authenticate incoming requests using **Laravel's typical session authentication cookie**. If that cookie is not present then Sanctum will attempt to authenticate the request using a **token in the request's Authorization header**.

You can limit out the API routes to only stateless request by commenting out the middleware

```php
// \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
```

Comment: That makes sense. However, I tried commenting it out and the request with the web guard still went through.